How to Prevent App Store Builds from Being Released to TestFlight Users?
I’m looking for a reliable way to allow beta testers to access new features through TestFlight while ensuring App Store builds aren’t accidentally released to TestFlight users. Downgrading from a newer TestFlight build to an App Store release could corrupt user data.
Selecting “Internal Testing Only” can prevent TestFlight builds from being released to the App Store. But is there a way to prevent App Store builds from being released in TestFlight? For example, could this be achieved with a build flag, configuration, or some other method?
One approach I’m considering is using a separate Bundle ID, effectively turning the TestFlight build into a distinct app. However, I’m unsure of the pros and cons of this approach, especially regarding developer experience and maintenance.
I’d appreciate any guidance or insights into best practices for managing this workflow.

Can you explain what aspect of a "store build" is unacceptable to a TestFlight user?
(I'm assuming it might be an effect of having a maint. branch and a dev. branch at the same time)
